# Perform Segue from Button in TableViewCell

Tags: swift, tableview, segue

I have a CustomCell class that has a button. I am using a prototype cell (not a .xib). I would like to have the button in a tableviewcell perform a segue and pass a value to a new class. How do I create a unique action for a button in a tableviewcell? Thanks!

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    ...

    selectedAreaCode = areaCodes[indexPath.row]

    // Configure Cell
    cell.areaCodeButton.setTitle(areaCode, forState: UIControlState.Normal)


    cell.areaCodeButton.addTarget(self, action: "segue", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None


    return cell
}

func segue() {

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toDialer", sender: self)
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    if(segue.identifier == "toDialer") {

        let nextViewController = (segue.destinationViewController as! PhoneDialer)
        nextViewController.passedAreaCode = selectedAreaCode
    }
}
```

Comment: So you have multiple "CustomCell" cells that each have a button that does something different?

Comment: use that `cell.button.tag = indexPath.row`

Comment: If you want cells of the same table to segue to different view, you have to give them different reuse identifiers.

Comment: They are all performing the same segue, but I would like the value passed to be different for each button. Ex: Array of ["1", "2", ...], where Cell 1 - Passes "1" to HomeView, Cell 2 - Passes "2" to HomeView, etc.  But right now, I have added a target for the button to segue, but it's only passing the last amount in the array

Answer (score 1):

There's a bunch of ways to get the tap action from your custom cell, but I'm assuming that you're trying to retrieve the action from a `UIViewController` because you're trying to segue.

Because you're dequeueing a cell, you briefly have full access to the cell in the scope of your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function. As long as you have the button as a public property of the cell, you can set that button's target to your segue method.

Also, because what you're trying to pass is in the title of the button itself, you can just access the sender from the selector.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = yourCell()
    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tap(:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
}

func segue(sender: UIButton) {
    // Perform segue and other stuff
    sender.title // This is the area code
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying this; however, the value that is passed is always the last  value in my tableView

Comment: I will add it to the main post

Comment: Updated, try it out

Comment: I will try it! I actually got it working by adding a tag to my button with `cell.areaCodeButton.addTarget = indexPath.row`, then in my segue function, I set selectedAreaCode as `selectedAreaCode = areaCodes[sender.tag]` and it works! Thanks!